# Spritekit Working with levels

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am new to SpriteKit and Swift and am looking for some advice. I am creating a simple level based game that progressively gets harder each level. Each level has a different layout and obstacles. I have a GameScene.swift file and GameScene.sks file. The game works but I am unclear on what is the proper way to handle additional levels. I am planning on making 50 levels. Do I need to create a swift and sks file for each level? Or is there a more efficient and proper way of handling this? Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are wish to make. A good way to do levels is to to make one GameScene for each level. But it is also possible to programmatically design the levels. If someone else design the levels then you should make single GameScenes for each level.